# How can I see what's different rebuilding a project with different project settings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, vcpkg

We've recently switched to using vcpkg on our solution and it's enabled by default on all projects. We discovered an odd bug in a DLL project where WinAPI methods fail when vcpkg is enabled, but succeed when it is disabled.

The project doesn't use any 3rd-party dependencies so vcpkg isn't required but rebuilding with vcpkg enabled causes the DLL size to increase by about 40KB / 15%.

It's proving a hard problem to figure out, but trying to see what's different in the two versions seems a good route of investigation. vcpkg shouldn't be pulling in things that aren't needed but it seems I want to be able to check:

1. what headers are used - maybe a different version is used from vcpkg
2. what libs are used
3. what symbols are linked from which libraries

We build using a static/MD configuration so all our vcpkg dependencies are static libraries but we link to MFC DLLs. We build for Win 10SDK, 142 compiler, WIN_VER 6 (Windows 7).

Setting vcpkg enabled/disabled is the *only* change I'm making, so how can I compare side-by-side what is going on to get some clue what's wrong?

Comment: [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference).

Comment: @IInspectable I've found that some help but looking around, turning on linker logging has shown more detail what might be going on.